# Rails sign up forms for different users using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two types of users pro and amateur. Is it possible to have same sign up page for both but show name field to pro users and hide it for amateur users when they are signing up?

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use **radio buttons** and on the selection of pro user, you can show/hide `name` field using Jquery/Javascript.

Comment: I don't understand, cause if user haven't signup yet, how can we know he/she is a amateur or pro?

Comment: That was i'm saying. Let user select with the radio button and on selecting it show/hide the name field

Comment: I have a dropdown Pro and Amateur users. My route file has `devise_for :users, :pro, :amateur` . I have different sign up requirements for both. So is it possible without using radio buttons show/hide fields depending on which they are or  instead have two sign up form?

Comment: Yes. On selecting a pro user from a drop-down, you can show/hide name field. So both users can sign-up in one form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following:

```
<% if request.fullpath.include?('pro') %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
<% unless current_user.amateur? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_type %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

make an method in User model called amateur? which return True/False.